# Better debugging in Visual Studio?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-2013

I have a program with thousands of lines of code that executes fine when run in Debug mode from Visual Studio. When I go to run that same debug executable from Windows Explorer, however, it gives me a "Debug Assertion Failed" error saying that the vector subscript it out of range. The line number is in `std::vector`, but I know that's not where the real issue is.

It's not like I can set a stop point to look at the call stack because I don't know where to stop it. Plus, Visual Studio isn't catching it anyway. I have 15k lines of code with dozens of vectors. There's got to be a way I can configure Visual Studio or the compiler to interrogate the program more to catch it when it runs from the GUI. I'm at the limit of my debug knowledge, teach me, wise ones!

I've ran dependency walker. There are some errors, but I don't think it's relevant. Just in case, here's what came up: http://screencast.com/t/q3MoPRVH

Comment: What about breaking into the debugger when the assertion fails?

Comment: It does come up and say "Press Retry to debug the application" but it never transfers over to Visual Studio. In fact, nothing happens. Abort, Retry, and Ignore all end with the window closing.

Comment: Then can you attach from Visual Studio before this happens?

Comment: Oh man, completely forgot about that. Couldn't do that before it happened, but attaching the process still got me close to the error and I see where it's going wrong now. Thank you! For the sake of conversation though, if I hadn't been able to do this, what would my next step be?

Comment: Or you can have your program crash and collect the crash dump to be analyzed by Visual Studio.

Comment: I don't see what could fail with attaching from Visual Studio (worst case scenario being that you add a `sleep` call to have enough time to do it). I'm not in front of a Windows computer right now so I'm not too sure about the options, I might have tried to see why debugging from the assert dialog didn't work in the first place. I know that there are registry keys for debug hooks, could have looked for that.

Comment: For ”Press Retry to debug the application“ to work properly, you need to configure the Just-in-TIme (JIT) debugger in the first place.

Comment: @Lingxi, In tools / options / debugging, I don't have a Just-In-Time page. Is there somewhere else I can configure that? Was following this MS guide: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5hs4b7a6.aspx

Comment: This looks like a case of unitialized variable.  Many debuggers will initialize variables, when executing in Debug Mode.  However, the operating system does not initialize variables for you.  The program should initialize all variables before usage.  Turn up your compiler warnings.

Answer (score 1):

The best option may be breaking into your code just at the time the debug assertion failed. In Windows, this is called Just-In-Time (JIT) Debugging. To use Visual Studio for this purpose, you have to configure it properly. If this [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5hs4b7a6.aspx) does not help you, try directly editing the Windows registry following [this guide](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff542967(v=vs.85).aspx). The registry value for Visual Studio is something like

`"C:\windows\system32\vsjitdebugger.exe" -p %ld -e %ld`

Answer (score 0):

After reviewing the code for uninitialized variables, I suggest you add some print statements to see where it gets to before it crashes.

Many times, these errors are attributed to uninitialized variables.